# Connect two devices Ubuntu and Windows via WiFi without router

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I would like to connect two devices via Wifi without using the router.

The ubuntu device has been configured like this.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.46 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.46 wlan0
```

And the windows one is configured manually at the Network Connection --> IPv4
IP: 192.168.1.47
Mask: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.1.46

However, I cannot ping one device to another. How should I do it?

Comment: If you do not have a router, then you likely have two different wireless networks and you cannot connect just like a router.  You may need to join by VPN or something similar.

Comment: What you're looking for is ad-hoc networking. Clear instructions are easy to find with google, Youtube also has good videos about it. Since I've never done it myself I'm not putting this up as an answer at this point.